# How do I make core-scaffold's menu button do more?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

How might I change the on-tap method for a core-icon-button dynamically? In other words, how do I override/hook into the core-scaffold's menu button to make it do more?

Use case: If on any page other than the main page, I want to change the menu button to be a back button and go back instead of slide open the menu. I'm using `core-scaffold` which already has a menu button that calls its own `toggleDrawer` method. I'm able to change the icon when on secondary pages (see my code), but how do I change the `on-tap="toggleDrawer"` to call a different method, or otherwise handle this? I'd prefer to avoid recreating what `core-scaffold` simplifies for me.

This is a method in my main app element:

```
void switchPage(Event e, var detail, Element target) {
    CoreScaffold scaffold = $['scaffold'];
    scaffold.closeDrawer();
    app.selectedPage = int.parse(target.dataset['page']);

    // Change the menu icon to a back icon.
    CoreIconButton menuButton = querySelector('core-scaffold::shadow core-icon-button');
    menuButton.icon = "arrow-back";
    // TODO: Now how do I call a goBack method?

    app.router.dispatch(url: target.dataset['url']);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it may be easier to just recreate the `core-scaffold` but leverage your own button that has the behavior you're after. It feels like you're breaking the encapsulation by using `querySelector` to change the icon, and even more so if you start altering the methods it's running from the outside.

This makes me think that it might be a good idea to turn `core-scaffold` into more of an example since, invariably, other developers are going to run up against this same dilemma.